# singularity : how to free loop devices?

Tags: linux, mount, bamboo, singularity-container

On a server, we run continuous integration jobs as runscripts of singularity image, e.g.

```
wget url_to_mysingularityimage.sif
chmod +x ./mysingularityimage.sif
./mysingularityimage.sif
```

In case this is relevant: in our specific case, the runscript is a bash script. It works great.

After executing the job, the image is deleted.

```
rm ./mysingularityimage.sif
```

But it looks like a corresponding loop device still exists, i.e.

```
losetup -a | grep mysingularityimage.sif
```

outputs something like:

```
/dev/loop27: []: (/path/to/mysingularityimage.sif (deleted)), offset 40960, sizelimit 831307776
```

As we run jobs, the number of loop devices increases. At some points, the limit number of loop devices is reached, and singularity fails with the error:

```
FATAL:   container creation failed: mount /proc/self/fd/3->/usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs error: while mounting image /proc/self/fd/3: failed to find loop device: could not attach image file to loop device: no loop devices available
```

Is there something we are doing wrong ? Is there a command we are expected to run at the end of each job to ensure the loop device is "freed" ?

(note: we use bamboo for continuous integration, and bamboo always performs the job in a new directory, which may explain why the same loop device is not reused over. Bamboo: https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo).

Comment: I searched the singularity github issues, and [this might be relevant](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/issues/5760) if shared loop devices are enabled.

Comment: I just found this documentation page, which explains how loop devices can be shared: https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/admin-guide/configfiles.html

Comment: in the past I have seen this error when a host directory was bound against `/` inside the container.